# Why I can not input "TJE" in excel 2007?

Tags: excel

Is there anyone encountered the same issue as me? When I try to type **"TJE"** in any cell of my excel sheet, Excel will change it to **"THE"** automatically.

Isn't a bug?

Comment: LOL. It is called Auto Correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug. It is called Auto Correct, and you can change the settings in the Tools menu.

Comment: Oh,my GOD. But I really need someone to input "TJE" when I design the template. =_=|||